# Can an EJB server side send an event to an EJB client side?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, openejb, bidirectional

I wonder if it is possible to do something along these lines:

1) Server side (EJB class)

```
@Statefull
public class SomeEJB implements SomeEJBRemote {

@Resource
private SessionContext sessionContext;

//(...)
public void someMethod(Record record){
    //(...)
    //Situation that requires the server to alert all registered listeners
    if(specialSituation){
        sessionContext.fireEventToListeners(new SomeEvent());
    }

    //Do something else...
}
}
```

2) Client side

```
//(...) 
SomeEJBRemote ejb = initialContext.lookup("SomeEJBRemote");
ejb.addListener(this);

void EJBEventListener(SomeEvent event){
    System.out.println("EJB server has sent an event!");
}
```

A) Is there anything in the Java EE specification that allows this?

B) I know that JBoss allows some sort of bidirectional communication, but can I do just like that example?

C) Is there anything like this in OpenEJB (or TOMEE)?

Answer (score 4):

It's easy to do with an embedded EJB container and an MDB in the client.  We have an example that does exactly that.

Check out the `monitor` module of [this example](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/openejb/trunk/openejb/examples/webapps/moviefun).

At 10,000 feet this example does the following:

Server-side:

- @Stateless bean that wraps access to an EntityManager
- JMS Message sent to a topic on all add/delete operations

Client-side:

- Embedded EJB Container/MDB receiving messages
- On receipt a notification is issued to the user via the `java.awt.SystemTray`

So the interesting thing about this technique is that it is fully transactional -- the EntityManager updates *and* the JMS messages sent are all part of the transaction.  If the database update fails, no JMS message will be sent.

Here's 100% of the client code from that example.  Doesn't take much to do what's described.

## The client "main" class

```
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.MenuItem;
import java.awt.PopupMenu;
import java.awt.SystemTray;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.TrayIcon;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class NotificationMonitor {
    private static TrayIcon trayIcon;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException, InterruptedException, AWTException, MalformedURLException {
        addSystemTrayIcon();

        // Boot the embedded EJB Container 
        new InitialContext();

        System.out.println("Starting monitor...");
    }

    private static void addSystemTrayIcon() throws AWTException, MalformedURLException {
        SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();

        URL moviepng = NotificationMonitor.class.getClassLoader().getResource("movie.png");
        Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(moviepng);

        ActionListener exitListener = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Exiting monitor...");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        };

        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu();
        MenuItem defaultItem = new MenuItem("Exit");
        defaultItem.addActionListener(exitListener);
        popup.add(defaultItem);

        trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "Notification Monitor", popup);
        trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
        tray.add(trayIcon);
    }

    public static void showAlert(String message) {
        synchronized (trayIcon) {
            trayIcon.displayMessage("Alert received", message, TrayIcon.MessageType.WARNING);
        }
    }
}
```

## The Client-Side MDB

```
import javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty;
import javax.ejb.MessageDriven;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Topic"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "notifications")})
public class NotificationsBean implements MessageListener {

    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        try {
            TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
            String text = textMessage.getText();

            NotificationMonitor.showAlert(text);
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

## Client jndi.properties file

This configures the embedded EJB container.  You could do this in code as well.

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.openejb.client.LocalInitialContextFactory
Default\ JMS\ Resource\ Adapter=new://Resource?type=ActiveMQResourceAdapter
Default\ JMS\ Resource\ Adapter.BrokerXmlConfig=broker:vm://localhost
Default\ JMS\ Resource\ Adapter.ServerUrl=tcp://localhost:61616
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is nothing like this in EJB.  I would suggest having the client either listen to a JMS queue/topic.  Alternatively, the client could export a listener object to RMI (effectively becoming a server itself), and then pass a reference to server; this technique would require quite a bit more infrastructure.

Comment: I thought about it, but the security requirements for RMI *and* the overhead (like you said, for the infrastructure) to duplicate the communication channels prevent us from using it. :-/